# Why does flutter fail importing my model?

Tags: flutter

Good morning,

I have been trying to import a model name transaction into my widget file.

Even if the path is correct, i get this error message

> Xcode's output:
> ↳
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:5:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/widgets/models/transaction.dart': No such file or directory
> import '../models/transaction.dart';
> ^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:4:8: Error: Error when reading 'lib/widgets/models/transaction.dart': No such file or directory
> import '../models/transaction.dart';
> ^
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:13:14: Error: Type 'Transaction' not found.
> final List _userTransactions = [
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:7:14: Error: Type 'Transaction' not found.
> final List transactions;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:13:14: Error: 'Transaction' isn't a type.
> final List _userTransactions = [
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:14:5: Error: Method not found: 'Transaction'.
> Transaction(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:20:5: Error: Method not found: 'Transaction'.
> Transaction(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart:29:19: Error: The method 'Transaction' isn't defined for the class '_UserTransactionsState'.
> - '_UserTransactionsState' is from 'package:expenses_app/widgets//user_transactions.dart' ('lib/widgets//user_transactions.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Transaction'.
> final newTx = Transaction(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:7:14: Error: 'Transaction' isn't a type.
> final List transactions;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:31:27: Error: The getter 'amount' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'amount'.
> '$${tx.amount}',
> ^^^^^^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:43:24: Error: The getter 'title' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'title'.
> tx.title,
> ^^^^^
> lib/widgets//transaction_list.dart:50:50: Error: The getter 'date' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
> - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'date'.
> DateFormat.yMMMd().format(tx.date),

The path is models/transaction.dart , but message Error when reading 'lib/widgets/models/transaction.dart' makes me think that i am doing something wrong with the import.

Please find below a screenshot of my files, then code of my 2 files :

[image]

models/transaction.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class Transaction {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final double amount;
  final DateTime date;

  Transaction({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.amount,
    @required this.date,
  });
}
```

widgets/transaction_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../models/transaction.dart';

class TransactionList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> transactions;

  TransactionList(this.transactions);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: transactions.map((tx) {
        return Card(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  vertical: 10,
                  horizontal: 15,
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text(
                  '\$${tx.amount}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Colors.purple,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    tx.title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat.yMMMd().format(tx.date),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

It looks like the 2 imports of models/transaction.dart fail but i can't find ou why ....

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is no file `import '../models/transaction.dart';`
There are three files in `widgets/models/`

`new_transaction.dart`
`transaction_list.dart`
`user_transactions.dart`

You need to either change the name of the relevant file or change your import to match the one of the file names.

For example `import '../models/new_transaction.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

- create a `src` folder beneath `lib`
- move models and widget folders into `src`
- Leave `main.dart` in `lib`
- Run app